# How can I disable the Android system notification that appears after I take a screen capture?

Tags: android, notifications, settings, screen-capture

Whenever I take a screen capture on my Pixel (I take several each day), the system gives me a "helpful" notification that the screenshot was captured. This is a terrible user experience for me since it stops my music, dings, and then shows an alert that I have to dismiss. I trust the system to actually take the screenshot. ...but it doesn't seem to be a notification that I'm able to disable since it is at the system level.

Anybody figure out how to disable this unnecessary notification? Is it just a bug that it can't be disabled?

To reproduce: if you want to take a screen capture hold down the power and down-vol at the same time until the shot is captured, then wait for the little animation and shutter sound letting you know it was captured. After that, you'll get the redundant ding and notification card.

Comment: I think that you should post this question in the StackExchange's Android forum. StackOverflow is strictly related to development questions.

https://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @4gus71n seems logical except that group feels like a ghost town...